# query in codeIgniter style

Tags: codeigniter

I have below query:

```
SET @sql = NULL ;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(  'select latitude,longitude,max(serverTime) as serverTime,', deviceID,  ' AS device from  d', deviceID,  '_gps' ) 
SEPARATOR  '  UNION ALL  ' ) 
INTO @sql 
FROM devices
WHERE accountID =2;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Can someone help me to write the above query in codeIgniter style....

ANd another thing is :What is the difference between writing the query in 1 and 2 formats

```
1. $query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE'); 



 2. $this->db->select("...");  
    $this->db->from(); 
    $this->db->where();
```

Will it have any effect on performance if we use 2nd style... Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please check [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)!

I think your question a little bit complicated to ActiveRecord so maybe you should do some parts  with raw query (eg. `GROUP_CONCAT`)

Difference between form 1. and 2.: in the second form ActiveRecord will protect your identifiers. I think the main advantage of ActiveRecord: you can implode your queries dinamically. Other advantage: maybe more readable the function calls, the big-big-big query string maybe a little unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(  'select latitude,longitude,max(serverTime) as serverTime,', deviceID,  ' AS device from  d', deviceID,  '_gps' ) SEPARATOR  '  UNION ALL  ' ) 
INTO @sql FROM devices WHERE accountID =2;"

$this->db->set('@sql', 'NULL', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);           

$query->execute();
```

Performance should be about the same for the 2 types of formats.  I prefer the second as it is more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I got the following error: _**Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::prepare()**_

Comment: @Jahmic where in codeigniter you have `prepare()` and `execute()`? Are you confusing PDO?

Comment: ah yes.  Confusion with PDO. Might have to roll your own.  I'll check into a bit more later.