# query in codeIgniter style

Tags: codeigniter

I have below query:

```
SET @sql = NULL ;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(  'select latitude,longitude,max(serverTime) as serverTime,', deviceID,  ' AS device from  d', deviceID,  '_gps' ) 
SEPARATOR  '  UNION ALL  ' ) 
INTO @sql 
FROM devices
WHERE accountID =2;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Can someone help me to write the above query in codeIgniter style....

ANd another thing is :What is the difference between writing the query in 1 and 2 formats

```
1. $query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE'); 



 2. $this->db->select("...");  
    $this->db->from(); 
    $this->db->where();
```

Will it have any effect on performance if we use 2nd style... Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [query in codeIgniter style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065474/query-in-codeigniter-style)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on what you mean by performance.

On the PHP side, it will take a tiny bit of processing (because it has to go through the database abstraction library).

On the SQL side, it will make no difference. CodeIgniter's active record class will compile the SQL statement and then run it, so as long as you write the statements correctly, you'll end up with the same query you had before.